# kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin FAILED e: Could not load module <Error module> - Android Studio Project

Tags: android

i got this error when i try build project.
I do not have any errors in compilator.

Source code: https://github.com/KarolCieslar/WyjazdyOSP/tree/firebase

```
> Task :app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin FAILED
e: Could not load module <Error module>


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I try to

- Restart and Invalidate cache
- Reopen project
- Update all dependencies
- Restart Android Studio
- Restart Computer

Comment: Can't build your project without the google.service.json.
"File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. "

Comment: @GlobooX Any luck on finding a way around this? I'm stuck with the same error right now. Thanks

Comment: @StéphanePéchard, i got same error yesterday, and I've just solve it moments ago,  there was a class that I don't use and it had some wrong imports .. for some reason the compiler was never showing this error .. only when I tried to commit files into temp branch then code analysis showed me the error .. try to perform Analyze Code in your project as well, you might find out what the problem is

Comment: Maybe this is related? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-58248/Kotlin-1.8.21-Compiler-crash-when-compiling-a-function-with-inferred-generic-types-from-a-nested-lambda

Comment: Which version of Android Studio were you on? Was it a beta version or stable?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I just had same error, for me, there was an unused class and it had some wrong imports .. for some reason the compiler was never showing this error .. only when I tried to commit files into temp branch then code analysis showed me the error .. I removed that class, rebuilt, and then this Error module message was gone, build was successful .. try to perform: **Analyze Code** in your project as well, you might find out what the problem is.

I've also read on some other forums, some guy facing same issue, for him it was generated code missing imports .. so you might also try to go through generated code in your project and check for missing imports there.

Comment: I had the same problem. After moving a class to another package, the IDE did not update the class import. I had to change the import manually. Now the compilation works fine.

Comment: Analyze Code didn't work for me. The only way I could find the problematic import was by navigating through each class one by one until the infamous red line appears in some code.

Comment: damn gradle not showing the error, 3 hs wasted with this issue. Thanks for sharing

Comment: omg you save my day. I rename the class but studio doesn't update usages and this error message was so useless

Comment: Analyze Code doesn't work for me

Comment: Thanks so much! I renamed a class, and this showed me exactly where to look.

Comment: It is also a useful thing to Clean cache/restart AS after "Analyze Code / Analyze Code Module dependencies".

Comment: SOLUTION: This (for me) has to do with migrating classes between projects. The "package" routes have changed, and instead of JetBrains noting this distinctly, you get the ever confusing "can't compile" error that tells you nothing. Check all your package lines in your classes. When you see a yellow underline, that means it doesn't think you've got it correct.

Comment: I had done a major merge from a branch whose package name had since changed, into an older branch.  I was getting this error, none of the analyze/inspect options were working. I had to do what @CassioLandim mentioned and open each modified file. In this case was about 300+ files.  Doing this I found multiple syntax errors that happened after the merge that amounted to too much damage for the compiler to pick up. After correcting these manually everything worked.

Answer (score 22):

Solution: Android Studio can't found out bad import. The problem was in one of the files. Old imports which are not contains in the application
I had to find it manually

Answer (score 11):

In my case, I was using Navigation Component with SafeArgs, and I was passing a custom Parcelable to a fragment. However, when I changed the package name for that Parcelable, it did not update in the nav graph file (ex: `nav_graph.xml`), I had to change it manually.

Comment: In my case I had similar issue: after refactoring (changing package name) the package name wasn't updated in nav graph xml. I had to check and change that manually and all worked fine after that.

Answer (score 5):

The measure problem is wrong import that IDE cant see during build. I find it by *running the test tasks*, tests cant be run and IDE shows me the wrong imports magically.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem. e: Could not load module 
In my case it was missing import in one of the refactored files. I was able to find it after crawling manually over each file. Idea finally showed red line error. Weird that you cant find it in analyze code or problems report in Intellij.

Here is my solution for future cases.
go to build gradle and disable kapt plugin and all kapt related imports like mapstruct etc.

When you now execute gradle build you will get place and error. Fix it and reenable kapt.

Answer (score 2):

There's a good chance that you might have recently updated the versions of Compose, Kotlin, or Accompanist. This could potentially lead to some migrations being required. For instance, the "accompanist-navigation-animation" library has been deprecated. If you upgrade to Accompanist 0.32.0 and Compose with BOM version 2023.08.00, you might encounter issues such as certain navigation code becoming unreadable and the possibility of a "module not found" error popping up. These issues would need to be resolved manually. For more details, refer to [the migration guide.](https://google.github.io/accompanist/navigation-animation/#migration)

I also had to update Google's protobuf dependency **id("com.google.protobuf")** from 0.9.0 to 0.9.4

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was

```xml
<argument
    android:name="quantity"
    android:defaultValue="-1"
    app:argType="int" />
```

instead of

```xml
<argument
    android:name="quantity"
    android:defaultValue="-1"
    app:argType="integer" />
```

1.5 hours gone

Comment: This was exactly my mistake. Thanks AndroidStudio for the helpful error messages.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that I was really stuck with this, but for me, it was a class that I just deleted and the references weren't removed by Android Studio!

Not even running the code analysis tool or code inspection. I had to make a walkthrough over the code that I was doing, and then when I opened the file the red line showed the missing reference!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

We just hit this issue - it was related to [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi), which uses kapt. The solution was to investigate our Kotlin files that defined Moshi objects to find the error.

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that the problem is in the navigation.xml file. It may be that the reference to some class in the argument tag is wrong. Because Android Studio cannot Refactor/Rename this file.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this error, I recently implemented an `AsyncResult` sealed class following this guide:
https://blog.devgenius.io/kotlin-sealed-class-with-generic-covariance-7e33875e7002

The problem was I was accidentally passing an `Any` generic to something that was typed as `Nothing`, like `AsyncResult.Error<Any>` instead of just `AsyncResult.Error`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, turns out I was trying to declare an argument in my nav graph file as a double which is not allowed. I replaced the double with a float

I replaced this:

```
<argument
        android:name=""
        app:argType="double" />
```

With this:

```
<argument
        android:name=""
        app:argType="float" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In my particular scenario, I recently updated Android Studio, and upon attempting to run the Gradle build, I encountered an error associated with the `kapt { generateStubs = true }` configuration in the Gradle file.

However, it's important to note that this kapt { generateStubs = true } error message was not the actual root cause of the build failure.

The underlying issue was related to the **incorrect number of parameters** being passed to a function, specifically a Composable function, from another class, specifically a ViewModel. Interestingly, Android Studio didn't directly highlight this particular issue. Instead, it presented the `kapt { generateStubs = true }` error, which initially led to some confusion during the debugging process.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, after creating new flavours I realised that we had missed adding the flavor dependency.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a Studio module not being updated. Individual Android studio modules were tracked by git submodules in our project and after a pull I had not updated the submodules.
Running `git submodule update` solved it.

Answer (score -1):

in my case I also had problem with imports. Build log helped me to localise the problem - it referenced the module where I was having the problem.
If you are working with any CVS, try checking the latest changes, it may help.