# Generic dagger errors since I modularized my app

Tags: android, dagger-2

Lately, I get totally unreadable errors when my project build fails. In the "Build Output" tab I just get the message `e: Could not load module <Error module>` with absolutely zero information of what is the error or where it comes from. It could be anything: a missing import, a typo, a missing argument...

It seems to happen since I modularized my app, I'm not sure because I did a lot of changes to its architecture lately.

Any idea what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It might be strange, but I've seen this error before and for whatever reason one of the files had an error within the imports and It didn't appear in the error message on build, so try just looking manually through the files for possible "unresolved references"

(also, see [kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin FAILED e: Could not load module  - Android Studio Project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76251497))

Comment: That's the thing. How do you "manually" look for errors when the compiler doesn't log them? Am I supposed to open all the files in my project one by one until I find the error? That's such a nightmare.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes, that's what I had to do :C